# Need to show dropdown with ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to show drop down `ng-select` items but data just like in the following image:

[image]

I'm using the below code:

```
<div id="all-activity-lists" style="display: block; padding: 0rem 1.25rem 0rem 1.25rem;">
    <ng-select
     [items]=activityList
     [multiple]="true"
     [closeOnSelect]="false"
     [searchable]="true"
     [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
     bindLabel="name"
     placeholder="Select Activity"
     class="filter-body"
     (change)="addActivity($event)"
     [(ngModel)]="selectedActivity">
     </ng-select>
  </div>
```

But I'm getting not getting the scrollbar:

[image]

Comment: You’re not getting a scrollbar because the list probably fits in the container (which can be scrolled)..

Comment: how can i reduce the length of container so that i can see the scrollbar ?

Comment: If you inspect the dropdown, you can put a hard max-height on there..